# How to remove curly brackets and ''=>" sign from association rules in R

Tags: r, csv, associations, rules, apriori

I want to know how to remove curly brackets and "=>" this sign from association rules generated by apriori in order to export the rules in csv file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And see `help("sub")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure returned by `apriori` contains the components (lhs, rhs) of the rules as factors. You can convert them to strings and remove the curly braces using `gsub`. Since you do not provide any data, I will illustrate with the built-in `Adult` data.

```
library(arules)

data("Adult")
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
    parameter = list(supp = 0.7, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))

LHS = gsub("[{}]", "", as.character(inspect(rules@lhs)$items))
RHS = gsub("[{}]", "", as.character(inspect(rules@rhs)$items))

LHS
 [1] ""                                    ""  
[3] "race=White"                           "race=White"            
 [5] "race=White"                          "native-country=UnitedStates"                  
 [7] "native-country=United-States"        "capital-gain=None"                             
 [9] "capital-loss=None"                   "race=White,native-country=United-States"       
[11] "race=White,capital-gain=None"        "race=White,native-country=United-States"       
[13] "race=White,capital-loss=None"        "race=White,capital-gain=None"                  
[15] "race=White,capital-loss=None"        "capital-gain=None,native-country=United-States"

RHS
 [1] "capital-gain=None"        "capital-loss=None"            "native-country=United-States"
 [4] "capital-gain=None"        "capital-loss=None"            "capital-gain=None"           
 [7] "capital-loss=None"        "capital-loss=None"            "capital-gain=None"           
[10] "capital-gain=None"        "native-country=United-States" "capital-loss=None"           
[13] "native-country=United-States" "capital-loss=None"        "capital-gain=None"           
[16] "capital-loss=None"        "capital-gain=None"
```

Comment: Thanks got it. I replaced it with gsub() function.

Answer (score 2):

Package `arules` provides a function called `DATAFRAME` that can be used to suppress the brackets and place LHS and RHS into different columns.

```
 DATAFRAME(rules, setStart='', setEnd='', separate = TRUE)
```